# Issue while using xgboost, error - "OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found"

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-science, xgboost

I have installed `xgboost` using following command on my **Windows 10 64bit computer** :

```
pip3 install C:\Softwares\xgboost-0.72-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
```

But while importing xgboost in one of my python files, it is failing with following error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-2b521fb1d447> in <module>()
      6 import sklearn.linear_model as linear_model
      7 import seaborn as sns
----> 8 import xgboost as xgb
      9 from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
     10 from IPython.display import HTML, display

c:\users\1022004\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\xgboost\__init__.py in <module>()
      9 import os
     10 
---> 11 from .core import DMatrix, Booster
     12 from .training import train, cv
     13 from . import rabit                   # noqa

..............................

c:\users\1022004\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    346 
    347         if handle is None:
--> 348             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    349         else:
    350             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found.
```

Can anyone help me out here? Also, I have tried installing `64bit xgboost wheel` file in my OS, but its saying that its not supported wheel file.

Comment: Did you try adding the path tho the package in the environment variable - PYTHONPATH per https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/2575 ?
There's another route to troubleshooting there as well.